# unable to find which sorting algorithm following code belongs to

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

I have written following code to sort numbers. The algorithm works, but I want to know which type of sorting algorithm (bubble, merge, quick etc.,) following code belongs to. Please help.

```
int SwapNums(int *Num1,int *Num2);

int main()

{
    int seq[5]={5,1,4,2,8};    
    int ArrayLen=sizeof(seq)/sizeof(*seq);    
    int i,j;

    for(i=1;i<ArrayLen;i++)
    { 
        for(j=i-1;j<ArrayLen;j++)
            if(seq[i-1]>seq[j])
                SwapNums(&seq[i-1],&seq[j]);
    }

    for(i=0;i<ArrayLen;i++)
        cout<<seq[i]<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Google the sorting algorithms you mentioned and see how each work. Then use a debugger step through your code and see what it is.

Answer (score 0):

It's a sort of bubble algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

It will most probably be a bubble sort algorithm. ( need the code of SwapNums(int *Num1,int *Num2); to be certain).

Comment: int SwapNums(int *Num1,int *Num2)
    {
    
    int temp=0;
    
    temp=*Num1;
    *Num1=*Num2;
    *Num2=temp;
    return 0;
}'

Comment: Then its confirmed, its a bubble sort algorithm. Selection sort has a different algorithm.

Comment: Can you please elaborate as to why this is a bubble sort?  One of the distinguishing characteristics of a bubble sort is that it swaps adjacent elements.  Furthermore, for each iteration to solve for the smallest number in a left-to-right fashion, wouldn't a bubble sort need to iterate over the sequence from right-to-left?

Comment: Your code resembles that of a bubble sort [link][http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/computersciencetheory/sorting1.html

Comment: @ArunA.S Can you elaborate as to how the original algorithm, not the code, resembles the linked bubble sort?  The linked bubble sort only compares adjacent elements (`y` and `y + 1`), and would never compare index `0` and `4` like the algorithm in the question does.  The article also mentions that the bubble sort can be optimized to stop sorting if no swaps occur through an entire iteration, as the list is already sorted.  If the original algorithm was given an input of `{1, 5, 4, 2, 8}`, the first iteration would make no swaps, and the final result would not be sorted.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [selection sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort) that performs a swap at each intermediate solve, rather than waiting until the end of an iteration to perform the swap.

---

Aside from complexity and space, sorting algorithms often have various characteristics which can be used for identity.  When identifying the type of an algorithm, it may be helpful to provide additional output during each step of the algorithm, then use this output to define traits.  For instance, here is a [example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3a56b14285f16cf1) based on the original algorithm that provides output at each step:

```cpp
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

void print(std::array<int, 5>& array)
{
  for(int i: array)
    std::cout << i << " ";
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::array<int, 5> seq = {5, 1, 4, 2, 8};
  std::cout << "Start: ";
  print(seq);

  for (std::size_t i=0; i < seq.size(); ++i)
  {
    for (std::size_t j=i+1; j < seq.size(); ++j)
    {
      std::cout << "index: " << i << "," << j << "; "
                << "element: " << seq[i] << "," << seq[j] << "; ";

      if (seq[i] > seq[j])
        std::swap(seq[i], seq[j]);

      print(seq);
    }
    std::cout << "-- next iteration --" << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "End: ";
  print(seq);
}
```

And its output:

```
Start: 5 1 4 2 8 
index: 0,1; element: 5,1; 1 5 4 2 8 
index: 0,2; element: 1,4; 1 5 4 2 8 
index: 0,3; element: 1,2; 1 5 4 2 8 
index: 0,4; element: 1,8; 1 5 4 2 8 
-- next iteration --
index: 1,2; element: 5,4; 1 4 5 2 8 
index: 1,3; element: 4,2; 1 2 5 4 8 
index: 1,4; element: 2,8; 1 2 5 4 8 
-- next iteration --
index: 2,3; element: 5,4; 1 2 4 5 8 
index: 2,4; element: 4,8; 1 2 4 5 8 
-- next iteration --
index: 3,4; element: 5,8; 1 2 4 5 8 
-- next iteration --
-- next iteration --
End: 1 2 4 5 8
```

Just examining the code itself, there are a few traits that can be identified:

- Complexity is O(n^2)
- No additional space is allocated, so space complexity is O(1)
- The algorithm does not use branched recursive, so it is not a divide and conquer algorithm.
- It is a [comparison sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort).

And when the output is examined:

- The ordered list is built from left to right.

  ```
  Start: 5 1 4 2 8
  End of 1st iteration: 1 5 4 2 8
  End of 2nd iteration: 1 2 5 4 8
  End of 3rd iteration: 1 2 4 5 8
  End of 4th iteration: 1 2 4 5 8
  ```
- The indexes being compared are not always adjacent.  In the first iteration, index `0` and `3` are compared.
- The elements being compared always include the currently known smallest unsorted element.  In the first iteration, `5` and `1` get compared, then `1` gets compared to all of the other elements.

With all of this traits, the algorithm most closely resembles a selection sort.  The sort pages on wikipedia often do a fairly good job at characterizing and illustrating the algorithms, but it can also be very helpful to consult an algorithm book.